# Получение всех фото из Instagram

Tags: запрос, instagram, instagram-api

Хочу получить все медиаматериалы своего же профиля в Instagram. После получения токена, я использую метод API [/users/self/media/recent](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self), который возвращает последние 20 фото. В описании сказано, чтобы перейти к другой двадцатке нужно использовать параметр `max_id` и id последнего фото в предыдущем запросе.

Пробовал получать информация по одному запросу на фото ограничивая количество параметром `count=1`. На 19-ом фото в ответе есть ссылка на следующее фото:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "next_max_id": "XXXXX",
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/230634764/media/recent?access_token=XXXXX&max_id=XXXXX&count=1"
   },
  "data": [
    ...
```

А вот на 20-ом фото таких ссылок нет.

Но, как я не пробовал, 21-ое фото мне так получить и не удалось:

```
{
  "pagination": {},
  "data": [],
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Может, я не тот метод использую или что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш аккаунт находится в "sandbox" режиме. В нем доступно получение только последних 20 материалов пользователя - цитата из документации: "Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users".

Что бы получить статус "live", необходимо отправить продукт на проверку. Но имейте в виду, если у Вас нет возможности авторизации любого пользователя, "live" Вы скорее всего не получите.

Comment: А если в моём приложении получение всех фото - основная функциональность и без него мне нечего отправлять на модерацию, то как быть тогда?

Comment: Попробуйте отправить на модерацию (видео работы продукта). Там же укажите суть работы, в ответе Вам все скажут. Но скорее всего сошлются  на правила, в которых указан перечень возможностей программного продукта, необходимых для получения "live" статуса.